# Google Recaptcha Enterprise: Create Service Client issue

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I've installed Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1 (Version 1.6.0) and I'm using  .net framework 4.7.1
I am following the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment#c to authenticate the Recaptcha.

but I'm facing the bellow issues. Code is throwing an exception when it tries to run the Create command in #132
[image]

[image]

The first Error was about version 1.46 'Google.Apis.Auth, because with Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1 (Version 1.6.0) installed Version 1.53 of 'Google.Apis.Auth
This is the exception message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.46.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Then I installed 'Google.Apis.Auth Version=1.46 after that I'm seeing a similar error but this time it's about version 1.53
Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException

```
Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.53.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Could anyone please suggest how it can be fixed?

Comment: It looks very similar to [this Github issue](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-dotnet/issues/333). You mentioned that you are using .net 4.7.1, could you update .net framework to 4.7.2 or newer and check again?

Comment: Any other suggestions?
TBH, I'm looking for any other option without changing the framework

Comment: How did you install framework? Using `Package Manager` or `.NET CLI`? What if you will try again to install version 1.53 using `Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth -Version 1.56.0`? you will again get issue that its missing 1.46?

Comment: Managed to fix this after adding Binding redirect in the web.config

 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.46.0.0" newVersion="1.53.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this after adding Binding redirect in the web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.46.0.0" newVersion="1.53.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
```